# Meaning of 一挺 in 雪人大肚子一挺，他顽皮地说：“我就是冬天。”

Tags: translation, word-choice

> 雪人大肚子一挺，他顽皮地说：“我就是冬天。”

What is the meaning of 一挺 in this sentence? I know 挺 can describe something as straight or erect, but I am confused why 一 is said before it.

Comment: 一 shows that it is a quick act. In this example, 一挺 means that do a quick act of making the belly move forward.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of 一看 in 打开盒子一看，里面是一只小猫?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/32743/what-is-the-meaning-of-%e4%b8%80%e7%9c%8b-in-%e6%89%93%e5%bc%80%e7%9b%92%e5%ad%90%e4%b8%80%e7%9c%8b-%e9%87%8c%e9%9d%a2%e6%98%af%e4%b8%80%e5%8f%aa%e5%b0%8f%e7%8c%ab)

Comment: @Raymond I think the use in that question is different from OP's. 一看 in that context introduced a *sequence*, while 一挺 here doesn't have that connotation.

Comment: 一挺 applies the same structure of "一" + verb as 一看

Comment: @Raymond 一 in 一看 denotes this sense: "（用在动词或动量词前面， 表示先做某个动作， 下文说明动作结果）" as in "经他这么一说， 大家又都有信心了。"

Comment: Or you could see it as ```雪人大肚子挺了一下```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This dictionary definition explains the use of 一:

> 表示猛然发出某种动作或突然出现某种情况
>
> E.g. 往起一站 / 右手一挥 / 眼前一黑。

Basically, this use of 一 expresses **the suddenness of an action** either *intentionally or unintentionally*.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what does a big belly do? It sticks out, protrudes!

Have a look [here](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%8C%BA), definition 2. especially: 凸出

2 伸直，凸出：～直。～起腰。

雪人大肚子一挺，他顽皮地说：“我就是冬天。“
The snowman, with his big belly sticking out, playfully said, "I am winter."

(There is a German joke about big-bellied men, this just reminded me of it, but you'd have to know German to understand it: Er ist ein Spiegeleimensch.)

Comment: Thank you for your input. My main question is why 一 is written before it.